# How many different necklaces problem

Tags: combinatorics

> How many different necklaces can be made from 20 beads, each of a
>   different color?

If I think this problem too simple then, I would answer (20-1)!. However now I thought that for example assume that we have 3 beads: blue-yellow-green. Then the blue-green-yellow necklace seems to be the same with blue-yellow-green necklace. (When I turn the first necklace, I can get the second one.) So I am wondering, is the number of different necklaces can be obtained is always the half of the ring permutation number? I mean for this question, is the answer (20-1)!/2 ? Also, how could I do the math if for example 5 of those beads were to be the same color? Would ((20-1)! / 5!) / 2 be the right answer?

Regards

Xentius

Comment: [Some related problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=necklaces).

Comment: In the case of $1$ bead, the answer is $1$. It is also $1$ for $2$ beads, since turning over produces nothing new. In all other cases, allowing turnover divides $(n-1)!$ by $2$. With colour repetitions, analysis is complicated. There is a nice group-theoretic approach due to Polya.

Comment: 314159th question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of calculating the number $p_n$ of necklaces when reflections are included among the admissible symmetries is just as easy, as the equivalence classes are still of the same size $2n$, giving $$p_n = \frac{n!}{2n} = \frac{1}{2} (n-1)!.$$

To compute this with Polya counting we need the cycle index $Z(D_n)$ of the dihedral group $D_n$, which contains reflections and rotations. It is given by
$$Z(D_n) = \frac{1}{2} Z(C_n) +
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} a_1 a_2^{(n-1)/2}, & n \mbox{ odd, } \\ 
\frac{1}{4}
\left( a_1^2 a_2^{(n-2)/2} + a_2^{n/2} \right), & n \mbox{ even.}
\end{cases}.$$
There is more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index).

The cycle index computation confirms the result of the basic analysis:

```
with(numtheory);
with(group):
with(combinat):


pet_cycleind_dihedral :=
proc(n)
local d, s, t;

    s := 0;

    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
    od;

    if type(n, odd) then
        t := n*a[1]*a[2]^((n-1)/2);
    else
        t := n/2*(a[1]^2*a[2]^((n-2)/2)+a[2]^(n/2));
    fi;

    (s+t)/2/n;
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

v :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local p, k, gf;

    p := add(cat(q, k), k=1..n);
    gf := expand(pet_varinto_cind(p, pet_cycleind_dihedral(n)));

    for k to n do
        gf := coeff(gf, cat(q, k), 1);
    od;

    gf;
end;
```

The code in action looks like this:

```
> seq([n, v(n), (n-1)!/2], n=1..12);
[1, 1, 1/2], [2, 1, 1/2], [3, 1, 1], [4, 3, 3], [5, 12, 12], [6, 60, 60], [7, 360, 360],
[8, 2520, 2520], [9, 20160, 20160], [10, 181440, 181440], [11, 1814400, 1814400],
[12, 19958400, 19958400]
```

**Remark July 4 2018.** Let me observe once more that with all beads a distinct color all orbits are the same size namely $2n$, giving the answer $(n-1)!/2.$ Polya counting is not needed here because Burnside says that if we have $n$ different colors and a color is to be constant on the cycles we need a permutation that factors into at least $n$ cycles. There is only one of these namely the identity which has $n$ fixed points. The number of ways of assigning the $n$ colors to these fixed points is $n!$ and we once more obtain $n!/2/n.$ On the other hand the cycle index becomes useful when we seek to classify bracelets according to the distribution of colors where colors may be repeated. For example with three colors red green and blue and a bracelet of six beads we get

$$Z(D_6)(R+B+G) = 
{B}^{6}+{B}^{5}G+{B}^{5}R+3\,{B}^{4}{G}^{2}+3\,{B}^{4}GR
\\ +3\,{B}^{4}{R}^{2}+3\,{B}^{3}{G}^{3}+6\,{B}^{3}{G}^{2}R
\\ +6\,{B}^{3}G{R}^{2}+3\,{B}^{3}{R}^{3}+3\,{B}^{2}{G}^{4}
\\ +6\,{B}^{2}{G}^{3}R+11\,{B}^{2}{G}^{2}{R}^{2}+6\,{B}^{2}G{R}^{3}
\\ +3\,{B}^{2}{R}^{4}+B{G}^{5}+3\,B{G}^{4}R+6\,B{G}^{3}{R}^{2}
\\ +6\,B{G}^{2}{R}^{3}+3\,BG{R}^{4}+B{R}^{5}+{G}^{6}+{G}^{5}R
\\ +3\,{G}^{4}{R}^{2}+3\,{G}^{3}{R}^{3}+3\,{G}^{2}{R}^{4}
\\ +G{R}^{5}+{R}^{6}.$$

This is where the Maple code may be deployed, using the command

```
pet_varinto_cind(R+G+B, pet_cycleind_dihedral(6));
```

The reader may want to verify some of these using pen and paper. For example the term $3B^4G^2$ represents the possibilities using four blue beads and two green ones which are: green beads adjacent, green beads with one blue bead and three blue beads separating them and green beads with two blue beads separating them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q_n$ be the solution for $n$ beads of different colors. This problem has special symmetries which make it possible to compute the answer without Polya counting, even though the latter can be applied and gives the correct answer. Quite simply, if all colors are different then the $n$ permutations that can be obtained by rotation from one another form an equivalence class and all equivalence classes are the same size, giving $$q_n = \frac{n!}{n} = (n-1)!.$$

Now if you wanted to do this by Polya counting you would use the cycle index $Z(C_n)$ of the symmetric group (the answers are the same). We have 
$$ Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$
The answer is then given by
$$ [q_1 q_2 \cdots q_n] Z(C_n)(q_1, q_2, \ldots q_n)$$
where the $q_k$ are being substituted into the cycle index and represent exactly one color.

**Remark Jun 19 2014.** If all colors are different then only the $a_1^n$ term from the cycle index contributes, giving $$ [q_1 q_2 \cdots q_n] \frac{1}{n} (q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_n)^n = \frac{n!}{n} = (n-1)!.$$

The Maple code to do this is as follows:

```
with(numtheory);
with(group):
with(combinat):


pet_cycleind_cyclic :=
proc(n)
local d, s;

    s := 0;

    for d in divisors(n) do
        s := s + phi(d)*a[d]^(n/d);
    od;

    s/n;
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

v :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local p, k, gf;

    p := add(cat(q, k), k=1..n);
    gf := expand(pet_varinto_cind(p, pet_cycleind_cyclic(n)));

    for k to n do
        gf := coeff(gf, cat(q, k), 1);
    od;

    gf;
end;
```

This confirms the results of the trivial computation:

```
> seq([n, v(n), (n-1)!], n=1..10);
[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2], [4, 6, 6], [5, 24, 24], [6, 120, 120], 
[7, 720, 720], [8, 5040, 5040], [9, 40320, 40320], [10, 362880, 362880]
```

Comment: but according to $$q_n = \frac{n!}{n} = (n-1)!.$$ if I have 3 different colored beads (say yellow&green&blue) then I should have (3-1)!=2 different results which are yellow-green-blue and yellow-blue-green. However are not they the same thing? I mean if I rotate the necklace 180 degrees over the y axis (take the image of the necklace on the mirror) then they are the same necklaces. So should not answer be 1? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So you have $n$ beads of $n$ colors. Just name one as "starting point" (i.e., cut the necklace on it), then you have only $n - 1$ beads to permute, i.e., $(n - 1)!$. But you can turn the necklace over, getting only half this as possible different necklaces. Thus there are:
$$
\frac{(n - 1)!}{2}
$$
necklaces.